# Dividing new created columns

Tags: mysql

orders_table:

```
orders_id_column   | user_id_column | final_status_column
----------------------------------------------------
1                  | 4455           | DeliveredStatus
2                  | 4455           | DeliveredStatus
3                  | 4455           | CanceledStatus
4                  | 8888           | CanceledStatus
```

I want to calculate the total number of orders, and the number of Canceled orders by user_id, and then the cocient between these two, to arrive to something like is:

```
user_id | total_orders | canceled_orders | cocient
---------------------------------------------------
4455    | 3            | 1               | 0.33
8888    | 1            | 1               | 1.00
```

I managed to create the first two columns, but not the last one:

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(order_id) AS total_orders,
    SUM(if(orders.final_status = 'DeliveredStatus', 1, 0)) AS canceled_orders
FROM users
GROUP BY user_id;
```

Comment: `,  SUM(if(orders.final_status = 'DeliveredStatus', 1, 0))  / COUNT(order_id)  as Q`

Comment: @daniherrera That's not very DRY though.

Comment: @MatBailie, of course you can use [CTE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html) if you are looking for DRY.

Comment: @daniherrera Asummes MySQL 8, many online services still provide 5.x :(

Comment: @MatBailie, you wrote 10 lines of code instead 1 just to DRY ? O_O :)

Comment: @daniherrera DRY isn't about shorter code. It's about removing fragility. By ensuring the SUMIF is only written once, future maintenance doesn't require the same code changes in multiple places. You may not personally value that, in general or just this case, but it is certainly what DRY is about.

Comment: @MatBailie, you are right, rewrite SUMIF is anti-pattern. I miss in your answer the 'simple approach' (syntactically correct) and then the DRY approach explaining why is better. Thanks about your comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an easy approach :

```
SELECT 
    user_id,
    COUNT(order_id) AS total_orders,
    SUM(CASE WHEN final_status = 'CanceledStatus' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) AS 
    canceled_orders,
   SUM(CASE WHEN final_status = 'CanceledStatus' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) /COUNT(order_id) 
    as cocient
FROM users
GROUP BY user_id;
```

Demo: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7yUJcuMJPncBBnrExKbzYz/136

Answer (score 1):

You could just use a sub-query.

Then you can refer to the newly created columns, as the outer query exists in a different scope (one where the new columns now exist).

(Thus avoids repeating any logic, and maintaining DRY code.)

```
SELECT
  user_id,
  total_orders,
  cancelled_orders,
  cancelled_orders / total_orders
FROM
(
  SELECT
    user_id,
    COUNT(order_id) AS total_orders,
    SUM(if(orders.final_status = 'DeliveredStatus', 1, 0)) AS canceled_orders
  FROM
    users
  GROUP BY
    user_id
)
  AS per_user
```

Note, selecting from the users table appears to be a typo in your example. It would appear that you should select from the orders table...